# Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int>' to expected argument type 'Range<_>'

Tags: swift, swift4.2

Using Swift 4.2, I get the title as an error in this function:

```
func jitter(range: Int) -> Int {
    return Int.random(in: 0..<range, using: SystemRandomNumberGenerator())
}
```

Questions:

1. What precisely does Range<_> mean?
2. Is there a better way to get this? I simply want a small random number inside an animation loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift compiler is giving you a bad error message. The problem is that the second argument to `Int.random(in:using:)` must be passed `inout` (i.e. with a `&` prefix). This works:

```
func jitter(range: Int) -> Int {
    var rng = SystemRandomNumberGenerator()
    return Int.random(in: 0..<range, using: &rng)
}
```

Even easier, omit the `using:` parameter altogether (`SystemRandomNumberGenerator` is the default RNG anyway):

```
func jitter(range: Int) -> Int {
    return Int.random(in: 0..<range)
}
```

Comment: Bang On! Thanks.